# WGET search files for string

Tags: linux, wget

I'm currently trying to work out a way to use the wget  to find a string within the html files of a site without downloading it locally. For example I am looking for any passwords that may be stored in a html file, how would I use wget to find that.

At present the only way I have been able to search is to do the following

Download the site

```
wget - r *sitename*
```

Use Find to located the text in the files

```
find . -type f -exec grep -H "stingvalue" {} ;
```

I have tried merging the commands but cannot get it to work.

Comment: Pipe the output of `wget` to `grep`.

Comment: Ok so I tried this with a few extra options to stop downloads and verbose output:
 wget -r --spider http://address -nv -nd | grep -r -e "stringvalue"

and so far it only found the previous commands in my history. What am I missing here?

Comment: you need to use `-O -` to make `wget` write to stdout instead of saving to a file.

Comment: Ok that worked. I was able to output the required HTML to a log that contained the exact data that I needed and from there I greped the output file to find what I needed without having to download the whole site. 
Thanks heaps. 

For those that want to know:

wget -r -O log.log *webaddress* -nv -nd | grep -r -e *string*

Comment: Just to clarify, you **are** downloading the whole site, its just that you're not saving (most of it?) to files on your local computer. I'm getting to your question late, so you already have a solution that looks good to me. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Barmar for the assist.

This will download the content of the required html file, without downloading the rest of the site. From there you can grep the file for the data you need:

```
wget -r -O log.log *webaddress* -nv -nd | grep -r -e *string*
```

Comment: *without downloading the rest of the site* - why do you claim so, whilst [wget man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/wget) states that: using **-r** or **-p** with **-O** may not work as you expect: Wget won't just download the first file to file and then download the rest to their normal names: all downloaded content will be placed in file